# How to get the Url for urlAction helper class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Asp.net MVC.

I want to send a url of my application in a mail.
So That instead of sending url like "/Home/Index", I'd like to use url.action() method, as I've modified my url for IIS 7.0 classic mode (e.g. "/home.aspx/Index").

So How can I do that in C#?

We may need to use [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505214.aspx), But don't have clear idea...

Answer (score 0):

http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/17/a-urlhelper-extension-for-creating-absolute-action-paths-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

or a better explanation on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")
```

The code above should produce: /MyController/MyAction 
Or in your case, using classic mode: /MyController.aspx/MyAction